# I have 2 Angular projects and want one of them inside the other

Tags: angular, git, git-submodules

I have 2 Angular projects, which I will name AngularApp1 and AngularApp2 in different Github repositories.
AngularApp1 is a big project and includes a lot of things in it and AngularApp2 is a smaller one built for a specific purpose.
I want to access AngularApp2 using a button in AngularApp1 that opens a page and shows it in the same domain as AngularApp1.
**I didn't know previously that AngularApp1 would access AngularApp2**

I have tried the **git submodule** and added AngularApp2 repository inside AngularApp1 repository successfully.
But I am struggling to display AngularApp2 in AngularApp1 application.

Comment: Have you tried module federation (https://www.angulararchitects.io/aktuelles/the-microfrontend-revolution-part-2-module-federation-with-angular/)? Sounds like it might be what you need. Not sure what you have tried and what specific issue u are facing

Answer (score 0):

One way to go about this is to reorganize your project structure so you can share modules. And then configure your routing so that your parent can access the child's components and be able to handle the routes.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it would be installing the AngularApp2 as a dependency of the AngularApp1 project. You could create a dist with `npm pack` and then install it into the AngularApp1 project with `npm i AngularApp2`